# Program not writing data into database VB

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am attempting to have the program copy the grade achieved by the user and write it into a database. The problem is it keeps coming up with the following error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO
>   statement.'

The code to calculate the grade is:

```
Private Sub StatsCalc()

    Dim Grade As String
    Dim sqlString As String

    If NoQ = 5 Then
        If Score = "0" Then
            Grade = "U"
        Else
            If Score = "1" Then
                Grade = "E"
            Else
                If Score = "2" Then
                    Grade = "D"
                Else
                    If Score = "3" Then
                        Grade = "C"
                    Else
                        If Score = "4" Then
                            Grade = "B"
                        Else
                            Grade = "A"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

        sqlString = "INSERT INTO loginDetails (ArGrade) WHERE UserName = '" & username & "'"
        sqlString = sqlString & " VALUES ('"
        sqlString = sqlString & Grade & "')" & ";"

        runSQL(sqlString)

    End If

    Percentage = (Score / NoQ) * 100
End Sub
```

runSQL is in a separate module and is as follows:

```
Module LoginModule

    Public Function runSQL(ByVal query As String) As DataTable

        Dim Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb") 
        Dim DataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter 

        Connection.Open() 
        DataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, Connection)
        dt.Clear() 
        DataAdapter.Fill(dt) 
        Connection.Close() 
        Return dt 

    End Function
End Module
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Insert statements don't use a WHERE clause.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: @Mary good advice in general, but not sure it would help with a SQL syntax error...

Comment: @ADyson I addressed the Sql in my answer. I just hate to see arithmetic attempted with Strings thus my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by:

```
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=login.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE loginDetails Set ArGrade ='" & Grade & "', ArPercentage='" & Percentage & "', ArMarks='" & Score & "'" & "WHERE UserName ='" & username & "'", cn)
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use parameters to avoid errors in concatenating strings and, most important, **avoid Sql Injection** (can destroy your database).

Your `runSql` function is not adequate to handle parameters. Also since you are running an Insert command, no records are returned so there will either be an empty `DataTable` or Nothing.

Database objects need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for you even if there is an error.

Access does not care about parameter names. I use them just to make the code easier to read. The parameters in Access must be added in the same order that they appear in the Sql command.

I wasn't sure if you mean to Insert a new record or Update an existing record. You show an Insert command but add a Where clause which doesn't make sense. I gave your both Functions so you can figure out what you are doing. Notice that order of the parameters added to the command are reversed because they appear in a different order in the Sql command.

```vb
Private Sub StatsCalc()
    Dim NoQ As Integer '= Get the value from somewhere
    Dim Score As String = "Get the value form Somewhere"
    Dim Percentage As Double
    Dim Grade As String
    Dim user As String = "Get the value from somewhere"

    If NoQ <> 5 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No database update. NoQ does not equal 5.")
        Return
    End If

    Select Case Score
        Case "0"
            Grade = "U"
        Case "1"
            Grade = "E"
        Case "2"
            Grade = "D"
        Case "3"
            Grade = "C"
        Case "4"
            Grade = "B"
        Case "5"
            Grade = "A"
        Case Else
            Grade = "X" 'Invalid entry
    End Select

    'Dim retVal = InsertGrade(user, Grade)
    'or
    Dim retVal = UpdateGrade(user, Grade)
    If retVal = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successful update")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error in update")
    End If

    Percentage = (CInt(Score) / NoQ) * 100
End Sub
Public Function UpdateGrade(ByVal username As String, grade As String) As Integer
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Using Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update loginDetails  Set ArGrade = @Grade Where UserName = @UserName;", Connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Grade", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = grade
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = username
        Connection.Open()
        retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    Return retVal
End Function

Public Function InsertGrade(ByVal username As String, grade As String) As Integer
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Using Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert Into loginDetails  (UserName, ArGrade) Values(@UserName,@Grade);", Connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = username
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Grade", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = grade
        Connection.Open()
        retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    Return retVal
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO loginDetails (ArGrade) WHERE UserName = '" & username & "'"
sqlString = sqlString & " VALUES ('"
sqlString = sqlString & Grade & "')" & ";"
```

with

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO loginDetails (ArGrade, UserName )"
sqlString = sqlString & " VALUES ('" & Grade & "', '" & username & "')" & ";"
```

I don't know how your table was created but I'd make sure that the field UserName is not of text type but numeric